# javascript january date issue

Tags: javascript, date, monthcalendar

```
function datecheck(){
    var dt1 = new Date();
    dt1.setUTCFullYear("2017");
    dt1.setUTCDate("1");
    dt1.setUTCMonth("1");
    alert(dt1.getUTCMonth());
}
```

When I execute this function I am getting 0 as alert but if setUTCMonth("2"). I am getting 2 in alert. Similarly if 3,4,5,6,7,8... is given then it alerts with same month that is passed then what is problem with January month?

But also I have observed that if

```
function datecheck(){
    var dt1 = new Date();
    dt1.setUTCFullYear("2017");
    dt1.setUTCMonth("1");
    dt1.setUTCDate("1");
    alert(dt1.getUTCMonth());
}
```

Behaviour change it start alerting 0 when 1 is passed. I am totally confused what is going on...

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript months go from 0-11. No it doesn't make sense. No it can't be changed because it would break backwards compatibility. Yes, it drives us all crazy.

Comment: Months (and days and years) are also numbers, not strings. Why would you go to the extra effort of writing `"1"` when you should just write `1`?

Comment: @JaredSmith Personally I like it - `['Jan','Feb','Mar'....][date.getUTCMonth()]` is a neat trick :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yup, pretty sure we've all written `const MONTHS = []` at some point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First off, mutating `Date` objects that way is inadvisable unless you *really* know what you are doing. Its better to pass the desired parameters to the constructor:

```
var jan1 = new Date(2017, 0, 1);
```

Note that I passed in zero. That's because unlike every other date-related counting, in JavaScript months go from 0-11.

Secondly, you are ignoring the impact of timezones. JavaScript constructs Date objects in the local timezone. For example, I'm GMT -5 at the moment.
If I do the following in my browser's console:

```
var dec31 = new Date(2016, 11, 31, 20); // 20hr == 8pm
dec31.getMonth();    // 11
dec31.getUTCMonth(); // 0
```

The five hour offset pushes the UTC time into the next month.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, given that OP is using all `[gs]etUTC*` functions...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol made some assumptions based on the result being dependent on the order the methods were being called in. Kinda like when you see some question with a fairly complicated title and body, but you know almost instantly its a dupe of "how to return a result from an asynchronous request" just by instinct.

Comment: Fair enough! :D